# What should I pass as argument to addMarkerSync()?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to modify the markers I've added to a google map. I've defined a BaseArrayClass Points. When I call a function, I want to traverse through Points and set each marker, without using Points.foreach().

```js
this.Points.forEach((data: any) => {
    let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync(data);
    let t: string = marker.get('title');
}
```

I want to use a regular for loop, but don't know what I should pass as argument to addMarkerSync().

```js
for(i=0;i<this.Points.getLength();i++) {
    let m: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync(argument);
    let t: string = m.get('title');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this.Points is probably an array. Then you can access the elements by index:

```js
this.Points[i]
```

But a more idomatic way would be a for..of loop:

```js
for (var data of this.Points) {
    let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync(data);
    let t: string = marker.get('title');
}
```

Comment: I tried the for..of loop, but it shows this error   `Type 'BaseArrayClass<any>' is not an array type or a string type`.